# When I set debug="false" in ASP.net, my website turns to white

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on asp.net MVC 5. I deployed the application and to increase the performance I researched and got to know debug should be set to "false". I did that but my website turns to colorless and still it is taking lot of time to load.

Comment: Hard to day, there isn't enough information here.  You could try explaining all of your steps and maybe in that we can see something that explains it.  Most relevant, tell us how you deployed your site and to what or where did you deploy it.

Comment: Forget about the deployment. I have developed a mvc 5 web application with bootstrap when i change settings in config file debug="false" then my site is changed to some other color.

Comment: Try to (Clean Solution) the (Rebuild Solution).

Comment: Inspect the pages source in your browser and check that all the javascript and style href links work.  If they don't, post one of the links here.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using bundles to render your css and they are optimized (minified + bundled) when debug is set to false.

now you have to investigate around here to know why something changes. Maybe a bundled file is not found, due to missing access right. Check in your browser's developer tools if everything is ok.